# What is this puzzle and what is this solving strategy?

Tags: strategy, puzzle-identification, sliding-blocks

This puzzle is a mini game in an app I recently downloaded. In the game it is referred to as a Mobius Puzzle(after some searching I found referenced as a TwoBik Puzzle). But I cant find any other names for it or how to solve it.

How it is Played:
The goal is to order the number left to right then top to bottom. You can slide each row or column in either direction moving every tile 1 space in that direction: the tile tht is pushed off the board loops to the other side of the same row or column.

See image for reference.

[image]

Comment: It seems to be called a torus puzzle. From what I'm reading, 4x4 grids are incredibly difficult for a human to solve, let alone 5x5, so I imagine this would be incredibly difficult. Theres a pdf [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/66c1/46fd2ed05cfaba26b4c28c25c3c2bfba2bfe.pdf) thats very long and complicated, but goes into great detail. Hope this helps!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Techniques for solving row & column sliding puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/93358/techniques-for-solving-row-column-sliding-puzzles)

Answer (score 3):

The simplest strategy is to

> think in terms of "supermoves" (like in Freecell). Denote N/S as swiping the middle column up/down. Similarly E/W means swiping the middle row right/left. The supermove NESW should permute three numbers only. It should be easy to solve any puzzle with supermoves described above.

As an analogy, one can

> solve a Rubik's cube using only elementary operations such as flipping two edges or permuting three corners etc. This algorithm always works, but don't expect to win a speed-solving competition any time soon!